# Open Graph link sharing does not work on only slack message box

Tags: nuxt.js, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, meta

I have a dynamic open graph tag is a meta tag in the nuxt.js app. Its preview is working great in Twitter, Facebook, Linkedin, skype, telegram, ... but it does not work in slack only.

```
head() {
    return {
      title: TITLE,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'twitter:card',
          name: 'twitter:card',
          content: 'summary',
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:title',
          name: 'twitter:title',
          content: this.job.title,
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:description',
          name: 'twitter:description',
          content:
            this.job.description.length > 100
              ? this.job.description.substr(0, 100)
              : this.job.description,
        },
        {
          hid: 'twitter:image',
          name: 'twitter:image',
          content: this.job.companyLogoThumb,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:title',
          property: 'og:title',
          content: this.job.title,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:image',
          property: 'og:image',
          content: this.job.companyLogoThumb,
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:type',
          property: 'og:type',
          content: 'website',
        },
        {
          hid: 'og:description',
          property: 'og:description',
          content:
            this.job.description.length > 100
              ? this.job.description.substr(0, 100)
              : this.job.description,
        },
      ],
    }
```

It looks good for most medias but only slack is not working.

Comment: Did you figure this out ? I'm kinda having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

This might help with this kind of problem:

If you're sharing a secure url, that is, https, then you need og:image:secure_url and possibly *also* og:image for the insecure image url.

I know at least slack won't work with an https site preview unless the og:image:secure_url tag is there as of April 2022.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, In my case, the image size was not fit on OG standard. I am not sure if this would be helpful for you.